# Semi collapse shiny dashboard sidebar, without using the given toggle in header

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Trying to add some personalized design to shiny dashboard - instead of using the sidebar toggle in the header of the dashboard to collapse and expand the sidebar, I would like to have this control in the sidebar itself as a button, and have it only do semi collapsing. See below:

[image]

I have already achieved the top (default sidebar toggle disabled, the button can completely collapse sidebar) and want to have have the sidebar semi-collapsed when click the button, as shown in the bottom.

Of note the sidebar toggle in the header normally looks like:
[image]

Reproducible code see below:

```
library("shiny")
library("htmltools")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinyjs")

# UI Page Starts
ui = dashboardPage(  
  skin = "black",

  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Title"
  ),


  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 250,
    fluidRow(
      useShinyjs(),
      column(8, align = "left", offset = 0, 
             style='padding-left: 28px;  padding-top: 10px', 
             h4(HTML(paste0("Project Lists")))),
      column(2, align = "left", offset = 0, 
             style='padding-top: 5px',
             actionButton("hideSidebar", icon("th"), style = "padding-top: 12px;")
      )
    ),

    # Remove the sidebar toggle element
    tags$script(JS("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';"))
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabBox(
      title = NULL, width = 12,
      id = "tabset1", height = "700px"
    )
  )
)


#Server
server = function(input, output, session) {

  #side bar  
  observeEvent(input$hideSidebar, {
    shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
  })
}

#
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: For the Semi-Collapsed, I believe the `shinydashboardPlus` package provides this sort of functionality by default, maybe have a look into that? There is a working example running [here](https://rinterface.com/shiny/shinydashboardPlus/).

Comment: @Snel23 I saw this example - unfortunately it has the default sidebar toggle in the header. I would like to see how exactly that is coded in and move it to the sidebar... but my knowledge of css is not sufficient to do it. Thanks for the comments

Comment: I thought you stated that you had achieved moving it? If so, all you have to do, is when the button is clicked, add a class to the body called `sidebar-collapse`, and the sidebar will become collapsed. Simply removing this class will make the sidebar full sized again

Comment: Hey @Snel23 Thank you for the comments. I now see your points and yes dashboardplus have semi-collapse by default. However, due to extremely lack of knowledge in js and css, I encounter more issues... Would you mind take a look at my new questoin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58616828/semi-collapsed-sidebar-re-designed-r-shiny-dashboardplus   Thank you!