# Semi-collapsed sidebar re-designed - R shiny dashboardplus

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Trying to make use of the Shiny dashboardplus semi-collapse sidebar, but run into some issues and would appreciate your advice.

A reproducible script:

```
library("shiny")
library("htmltools")
library("shinydashboard")
library("shinydashboardPlus")
library("bootstrap")
library("shinyjs")


# UI Page Starts
ui = dashboardPagePlus(

  title = "Shiny App",

  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Title with A Few Other Things",
    titleWidth = 530
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    fluidRow(
      useShinyjs(),
      column(8, align = "left", offset = 0, 
             style='padding-left: 28px;  padding-top: 10px', 
             h4(HTML(paste0("Project Lists")))),
      column(2, align = "left", offset = 0, 
             style='padding-top: 5px',
             actionButton("toggleSidebar", icon("th"), style = "padding-top: 12px;")
      )
    ),

    # Remove the sidebar toggle element
    tags$script(JS("document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-toggle')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';")),

    fluidRow(
      h4(HTML(paste0("Contents that are not supposed to show when collapsed.")))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody()
)



#Server
server = function(input, output, session) {
  #side bar  
  observeEvent(input$toggleSidebar, {
    shinyjs::toggleClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
  })
}

#
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this example, I removed the default dashboardplus toggle-sidebar button, and added a new one to the sidebar top right. (Of note, even I use the default one, it ends up to be the same issue) When click to collapse the sidebar, the sidebar itself semi-collapse as expected. However, I would like to also

1. get rid of the items in the sidebar when semi-collapsed.
2. add "project list" vertically to the semi-collapsed sidebar.
3. leave the header as is, without collapsing

Below I am showing first what it is right now and what I want it to be. Thanks so much in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer to all of your questions, but at least a partial one to solve the logo/title issue.

I did a lot of digging through the CSS of this item (i also happened to need this for my application), and found a solution in CSS.

The `230px` is the default width of the logo span, but yours seems longer, so you might have to change all occurences of `230px` with the width of your logo span (you should be able to find this by using inspect element and hovering over it)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .logo {
    width: 230px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-mini.sidebar-collapse .main-header .navbar {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-header .navbar {
    margin-left: 230px !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .main-header .logo, .main-header .navbar {
    width: 100% !important;
    float: none;
  }
}

.main-header .logo {
  width: 230px;
}
```

If you don't know how to source a CSS file in your shiny app, you can add

```
tags$head(
  includeCSS("styles.css")
)
```

(where `styles.css` is your CSS file including this code)
to the top of your initial tab's `fluidPage()` (or whatever it is you render the page)